# Sending multiple spinner data to a new window on a button click

Tags: android

Actually i was working on multiple spinner window and wanted to know how to send the selected spinner elements to a new window on clicking a OK button on my existing window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a way to send data between activities.

Well, the easy and right way to do so, is by putting extra to your intent. Like so

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("spinnerData", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

That should do

Comment: Actually you got me correct but i wanted to send multiple data and that too the data selected from spinner so is the code you provided should work well there??